# Need to access service in function

Tags: angular, restangular, angular2-services

I have a service (AuthService) that I need to access in my `restangularInit` function (in my app.module.ts) but I don't know how, I can't get access to it.

I have tried to move it to the class AppModule but by then it´s to late.

Calling the service functions eg. `getToken` works as expected.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { RestangularModule } from 'ng2-restangular';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './components/product/product.component';

// Services
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

export function restangularInit(RestangularProvider, AuthService) {
  console.log(AuthService); // this is undefined
  let token = AuthService.getToken(); //This is what I want to do
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('api');
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders(
    {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
  );
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    RestangularModule.forRoot(restangularInit)
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ],
  entryComponents: [ProductComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static method `getToken()` then you can access it like you did in your code.

```
let token = AuthService.getToken(); //This is what I want to do
```

Comment: the problem is that the service uses a promise to fetch the token from localforage. so the requests are sent before the token is set :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ng2-restangular/tree/f84787940037bd08d78bfb05bb31f2ac74503884#configuring-in-the-appmodule-with-dependency-injection-applied) you can do it like::

```
RestangularModule.forRoot([AuthService], restangularInit)
```

and then

```
export function restangularInit(RestangularProvider, authService: AuthService) {
  console.log(authService); // this is AuthService instance
  let token = authService.getToken(); //This is what I want to do
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('api');
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders(
    {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
  );
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the service uses a promise to fetch the token from localforage. so the requests are sent before the token is set :(

Comment: Why you don't get token before?

Comment: There are a lot of options to do that like APP_INITIALIZER, canActivate, resolver

Comment: When app is bootstrapped I run the AuthService localforage.getItem('auth').then((auth) => { extracting the token here });" but if the response from server is slow then the components will do the request before the promise is resolved.